# Geth eth.sendTransaction does not work

Tags: ethereum, geth

I'm learning ethereum and tried private network with Geth 1.7.3-stable.

Accounts[0] has 105 eth in private network and I tried to send eth like below.

But eth.sendTransaction command returns only 
"0xaf571929f95ddeaab8761d719dba3c852f5d4f9895968a905c275561eaf57ae6".

And accounts[1] doesn't receive any eth.

```
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
105000000000000000000
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0])
Unlock account 0x24636f1423f131f5441fbee83323c53c59af247d
Passphrase: 
true
>  eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(2, 'ether')})
"0xaf571929f95ddeaab8761d719dba3c852f5d4f9895968a905c275561eaf57ae6"
> 
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])
0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: From what you've described, it seems like you're running your node (constant functions return correctly), but are not mining any transactions.

Comment: Yes, I made genesis file and created private net. I tried `start mining` before but returned null. Is this the reason? What should I do next?

Comment: I realized I was wrong. Mining wasn't actually started before. Now I get correct result . But  `miner.start()` still responds null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check and make sure the transaction is reaching your blockchain. Set up a listener using

```
web3.eth.filter("pending").watch(
    function(error,result){
        if (!error) {
            console.log('Tx Hash: ' + result);
        }
    }
)
```

Once the listener is set up, run your `sendTransaction` again and confirm you're getting the log statement. If so, you're submitting the transaction correctly.

As mentioned in the comment, next thing is to make sure the transaction is mined. There's a few ways you can do this:

1. You can mine in the geth console. If you didn't start geth in console mode, you would need to either restart it, or attach to it via `geth attach` in another terminal. In the geth console, you can start mining with `miner.start()`. It will return null, but you should see activity in your geth output indicating mining has started. To stop mining, type `miner.stop()`.
2. You can download a separate mining app, like ethminer. Just download it and start it while `geth` is still running.

Any pending transactions should be picked up.